# Reconsider UI for home page and questions page

Tags: feature-request, design, question-lists

The UI for the multiple questions list is confusing to me ([and apparently to some others](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1427/3966)). Various issues with the current model are described on [this UX.meta post](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1427/3966), but I will try to briefly describe some of them below. The following images are from the [Security SE site](https://security.stackexchange.com/), but the issues are the same on other SE network sites.

The home page looks like this

[image: active | features | hot | week | month]

and the questions page looks like this.

[image: newest | featured | frequent| votes | active | unanswered]

The entries on each list also look different for no apparent reason.

Home page entry:
[image: home page entry]

Questions page entry:
[image: questions page entry]

Here are the issues that I think are problematic:

- **It isn't immediately obvious which page will contain the list you are looking for**. I don't know the reason why one list has the things it has or why the other list has the things it has, so I can't guess where to find what I'm looking for. **This issue is compounded by the fact that both lists contain `active` and `featured`**, because it means that the separate pages don't have individual purposes.
- **The only way to get to the lists on the home page is to click the site's logo**. This means that if I want to find the lists that are only on the home page (`hot`, `week`, `month`, `interesting` on StackOverflow) I have to discover it through a hidden link. When I'm looking for the list of, say, hot posts, pressing the site logo doesn't occur to me.
- **If I am browsing through different lists, I have to constantly jump back and forth between these pages**. If I am on Stack Overflow and I want to monitor both the `newest` list and the `interesting` list, I have to switch between pages, which is a more thought-intensive process than switching through tabs.

---

Note that I am not suggesting *how* to fix these issues. It probably isn't trivial and I am not a UX expert. I am only asking that it be fixed. If you have an idea about how to resolve this confusion, you can post it as an answer.